# MySQL-how to query to get all records and distinct count of specific column in single query

Tags: php, mysql

I have the table with three fields.

```
id name place
 1 A    x
 2 A    v
 3 B    z
 4 A    a
```

I have the query already like this,

```
  select Id
       , Place 
    from tbname 
   where Name like '" . mysql_real_escape_string( $name, $sql ) . "'
```

This will also do wild card matching with '%'

Now what I want is count of distinct values of 'Name' field in the above query without affecting the previous result.

If the wild card matches all the values in 'Name' field,the count is 2.

If I give like,

```
select Id
     , count(distinct Name) as count
     , Place from tbname 
 where Name like '" . mysql_real_escape_string( $tidbit, $sql ) . "'
```

This will return,

```
Id:1
count:2
Place:x
```

But I want all the matches as well as count like,

```
  Id:1,2,3,4
  count:2
  Place:x,y,z,q
```

Is there any way to do this in single query or any function is there in sql or php?

Please help me to figure out this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your DB seriously need normalization.

Comment: @abhikchakraborty I don't think so. I think it's just the strange way the OP has presented the question - but I might well be mistaken!

Comment: In general, aggregating queries need to know *what* they're aggregating. A GROUP BY clause can help with that.

Comment: @Strawberry may be I had mistaken too, since the data is presented as comma separated strings perhaps it was other way around. However the expected output made be think so.

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Answer (score -1):

i think

```
select Res1.id,Res1.cnt,Res2.place from (select id,count(distinct Name) cnt 
from tbname groupby id) res1 inner join
select  distinct id ,place from tbname group by id ) res2 on 
res1.id=res2.id
```

Comment: Maybe. Your question just isn't clear enough to answer definitively. If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.